# How to cache a block in block_html cache type in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, cache, block-cache

I have a block file that does heavy data processing due to which my product page PHP rendering time increases above 2 seconds. I have disabled `page_cache` in my Magento 2 system so i cannot use `cacheable="true"` in my layout file that loads this block file with it's template. I am looking for a solution where i can cache this file code into `block_html` cache type. Can anyone please tell me the solution on how i can implement this functionality.

My `SampleClass` is below which is extending core Magento 2's `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` class:

```
class SampleClass extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
 //rest of my code like __construct and other custom methods.
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally got a solution for the above question.
I have used two methods `getCacheLifetime()` and `getCacheKeyInfo()` of the core Magento 2 template block file and overridden those two methods of the class: `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock`.

The code looks like below:

```
//below code to set the life time of the cache
protected function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return parent::getCacheLifetime() ?: 3600;
}

//below method to keep cache key unique for each product page.
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    $keyInfo     =  parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
    $keyInfo[]   =  $this->getProduct()->getId(); // adding the product id to the cache key so that each cache built remains unique as per the product page.
    return $keyInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just add di.xml on your frontend area as below:

```
<type name="MyBlock">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="cache_lifetime" xsi:type="number">3600</item>
            <item name="cache_key" xsi:type="string">UNQKEY</item> // Not needed unless same block name and multiple outputs based on pid or something
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: this solution is not working in magento 2.4.5